# Order of "Favorites" Links in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#

How can I retrieve the order of the "Favorites" links in Windows Explorer? As visible in the following screenshot, they are not necessarily in alphabetical order.

[image: Windows Explorer screenshot]

**Edit**

Okay, a little more detail.

Windows Explorer apparently saves the order of the "Favorites" links - which is how it loads the order each time the user opens a new Explorer window. In my app I have a tree view similar to the one in Windows Explorer. How can I load into my app the "Favorites" order state that Windows Explorer saved?

The actual links themselves are stored (on Windows 8) in %USERPROFILE%\Links. (And please no comments about a "better" way to read this using `KnownFolderId` - which I *am* using in my code.) However, the only way I can retrieve these items would be to use `Directory.GetFiles` - which, obviously, returns the items in alphabetical order.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I have not been able to try anything. This is one of those problems where you either know how to do it or you don't. The only thing I could do was to browse through Google and the VS documentation - which I did for over 20 hours.

Comment: No, you could try to retrieve the favorites themselves? Or to do _anything at all_ having to do with favorites.

Comment: What do you mean about retrieving the order? I assume you mean "retrieving the favorites in the order listed", but you don't make that clear.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I know how to retrieve the favorites (%USERPROFILE%\Links). I just don't know how Windows Explorer orders them.

Comment: It orders them in the order you put them in.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: And where does it store that order? I want my app to read that.

Comment: Please update your question to state that this is what you want.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Okay, how's the edit?

Comment: Much better, thank you.